# how to properly align multiple label-text box pairs (with and without floats)?

Tags: html, css

I wrote the following :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="filter">
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text"/>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="filter">
            <label>Id: </label><input type="text"/>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

with the CSS as :

```
span.filter{
    width: 50px;
}
input{
    text-align: right;
}
label{
    text-align: left;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}​
```

But the result is as shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/krL7z/1/) fiddle. Some people suggest using floats, but why is this not working ?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? Your code is working exactly as I'd expect

Comment: The textboxes should be aligned

Comment: As in vertically aligned with each other?

Comment: yes.. vertically aligned.. I realize that I can't give width to spans.. so I removed the spans.. and gave li that width..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this effect using floats, set the display property of your labels to block, declare their width, and float them left. Then float your inputs left and us clear:left on the label elements so that they don't wind up all on one line.

so:

```
label{
display:block;
width:50px; /*arbitrarily determined */
float:left;
clear:left;
} 

input{
float:left; 
}
```

See the result in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krL7z/6/).

You can also do this using display:inline-block (and hence less code) as indicated in xiaoyi's answer.

Another way is to use table cells, which (while some consider them semantically appropriate to forms) are not something you generally want to rely on for layout.

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary to use `float`. There are many ways to make it work:

Eg.

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krL7z/7/

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a situation where you know you are able to limit the browsers you support (Explorer higher than IE7) and all the others Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari ... then you can use the display:table and display:table-cell to layout the cells in table fashion - without the actual table mark-up.

```
span.filter 
{    
    display:table;
}
span.filter label, span.filter input
{    
    display:table-cell;
}
```